JAX-RS implementation for Vert.x that supports coroutines?
There are samples for using JAX-RS and coroutines with Vert.x.
But how can I have both?
Resteasy-vertx doesn't seem to support coroutines.
Quarkus REST (FKA  RESTEasy Reactive) supports JAX-RS, coroutines and Vert.x.
The problem is I don't really care for other parts of Quarkus and would rather not pull in all that complexity. E.g. I don't need JTA or Hibernate support.
If there is a way to only use Quarkus REST without all other parts of Quarkus that would be fine. But is it?
Ultimately I don't need JAX-RS, just a more convinient way to declare my REST endpoints (including bean validation). A library that works similiar to JAX-RS but doesn't implement that specification would be fine too.

There is no such thing as far as I am aware. I obviously encourage people to use Quarkus REST, but I am biased :)

I’m not sure why you don’t want to use JAX-RS…-anyways, you can use Reactive Routes as an alternative, however this used to have some limitations. And I’m not sure whether it is still actively maintained. For example, security, metrics, tracing, etc. and other stuff that work out of the box with JAX-RS might not work with it.

I never said I don't want to use JAX-RS. I don't want to use Quarkus as I don't need most of it. I'm only interested in JAX-RS but I don't see a way to just use Quarkus REST without pulling in all the rest of Quarkus

what you write about Reactive Routes is a bit concerning. There is no information in that docs that it's not actively maintained. Are there other parts of Quarkus that are silently not maintained anymore?
